# Standard keyframes in react js doesn't work

Tags: css, reactjs

Just a simple question about keyframes in css and react js. Have 2 types of animations, first one works but second one no

The second example doesn't work even in global css file and in module.css too

The first example:

```
import React from "react"; 
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div className="section" style={{ background: "transparent" }}>
      <h1>HOME</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

CSS:

```
.section{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  animation-name: delay;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  z-index: -1;
}
@keyframes delay {
  0%{transform: translateY(30px)}
  100%{transform: translateY(0)}
}
```

Second example:

```
function Wings() {
  return (
    <div className='wings'>
      <div className='rightWing' >
        <img src={rightWing} alt="" />
      </div>
      <div className='leftWing'>
        <img src={leftWing} alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CSS:

```
.wings{
  z-index: 10;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.leftWing{
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 85% 5%;
  transform: translateX(25%) rotate(90deg);
  animation-name: left-wing;
  animation-duration: 2sec;
}
.rightWing{
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 15% 5%;
  transform: translateX(-25%) rotate(-90deg);
  animation-name: right-wing;
  animation-duration: 2sec;
}
@keyframes left-wing {
  0%{transform: translateX(25%) rotate(90deg);}
  50%{transform: rotate(0deg);}
  100%{transform: translateX(25%) rotate(90deg);}
}
@keyframes right-wing {
  0%{transform: translateX(-25%) rotate(-90deg);}
  50%{transform: rotate(0deg);}
  100%{transform: translateX(-25%) rotate(-90deg);}
}
```

So the question is - Why it doesn't work ? :D

UPD: GUYS ! Always set 2s 3s etc NOT 2SEC :D

Comment: probably because you define transform 2 times... I didn't try it but basically one is overwriting the other

Comment: @İlker but the same css code works on vanilla js

Comment: Is this just a copy-paste mistake or are you missing a closing curly brace `}` for the `@keyframes delay` ?

Comment: @gru just copy paste mistake, first example of keyframe works, but second ...

Comment: I see 3 animations in your code: delay, left-wing, and right-wing. which one works and which one doesn't?

Comment: @gru wings don't work

Comment: @gru I've find solution, updated my post :D

Comment: Closing as a typo because it should simply be `2s` instead of `2sec`

Comment: @Terry i've already added this at the end of ques